# How to automate dropdown list in the kendo ui using Webdriver/Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I tried to run the the script in webdriver,am getting an error like as below
script:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tabstrip']/div[1]/span/span/span[1]")).click();
```

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ddlschedule_option_selected']")).click();
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
>   Command duration or timeout: 35 milliseconds

Comment: If it a drop-down list can you use regular approach to select  the element from the it, also you can share the URL if the page is publicly available?

Comment: sorry itz not public...can u please help me to resolve the timeout problem in webdriver/java

Comment: Can you separate the findElement() call from the click() call, so you know which one is throwing the exception? E.g. is it finding the element but unable to click it? or not finding the element?

Comment: If it's not finding the element, you'll need to show us the structure of the HTML, or else we won't be able to evaluate whether there are problems with the XPath expression.

Comment: Actually the drop down is getting listed, but i cant able to select the value from it..;(

Comment: Have you tried this ?  http://rupeshrshinde.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-select-option-from-dropdown.html

Comment: actually the this is its kendo ui drop down,,not a normal html drop down... refer the html code :     http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index

Comment: I referred the drop-down in the url you've provided, and was able to automate it. In context of the above URL, you've to click on the select drop-down first, then the list of options comes up. For it, the HTML snippet is actually present below in a **div with class attribute "k-animation-container"** wherein you can easily get the xpath/css of the option you want to click on.  Hence, if you can provide the relevant HTML snippet of the dropdown you're clicking and the HTML snippet of the div element that contains the list of all options, it will be easier to help you out.. Thanks.. :)

Comment: thanks  for you effort,now am facing new issue like sometimes the options got selected, sometimes not..i have user : thread.sleep(15000); first time itz executed successfully,again i tried to run the code,but the options is not got selected throws timeout error..;(

Answer (score 0):

Try using javascript executor below is the example in c#

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("$('#tableID:contains('option')').prop('selected', true)");
```